# iPhone development. EXC_BAD_ACCESS when passing data between views

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access

I have an app which has a simple TableView and pushes to a detailed view when clicking an item. But I am trapped with EXC_BAD_ACCESS when passing a Ringtone* object to detailed view using property.

Here is the definition of ringtone class, which stores the data:

```
@interface Ringtone : NSObject {
    NSString *ringtoneName;

    NSString *desc;

    NSString *fileName;

    NSDate *date;

    int cId;

    int rId;

    int downloads;

    int fileSize;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *ringtoneName;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *desc;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *fileName;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *date;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int cId;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int rId;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int downloads;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int fileSize;

@end
```

Here is the property definition in DetailedViewController:

```
@interface RingtoneDetailViewController : UITableViewController {
    Ringtone *R;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Ringtone *R;

@end
```

Then in the item selection event:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RingtoneDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[RingtoneDetailViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    Ringtone *r = [ringtoneList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    detailViewController.R = r; //EXC_BAD_ACCESS This line

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    [detailViewController release];

}
```

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurred when assigning the R property. Where did I make mistakes?

Comment: OT: you should copy (not retain) concrete types by default: that is, Ringtone: ringtoneName, desc, fileName, date

Comment: you need to alloc memory to Ringtone object before assigning to  detailViewController object.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check if the `object` of `Ringtone` is `allocated` properly.

Comment: Where should I put allocation code for the ringtone object in detailView?

Comment: No you have to allocate it before assigning any value to it.

Answer (score 0):

you Have to synthesize the property in implementation class.
Because if you are create a property and if you want to use that property in other class then u must synthesize that property.